# Regex expression to match on hyphens in words within sentence based on occurrences of hyphen

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match on hyphens in a word but only if the hyphen occurs in said word say more than once

So in the phrase "Step-By-Step" the hyphens would be matched whereas in the phrase "Coca-Cola", the hyphens would not be matched.

In a full sentence combining phrases "Step-By-Step and Coca-Cola" only the hyphens within "Step-By-Step" would be expected to match.

I have the following expression currently, but this is matching all hyphens separated by non-digit characters regardless of occurences

```
((?=\D)-(?<=\D))
```

I can't seem to get the quantifiers to work with this expression, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java Regex Solution:**

```
(?<=-[^\s-]{0,999})-|-(?=[^\s-]*-)
```

[Java RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZcehM/5)

---

**PCRE Regex Solution:**

Here is a way to match all hyphens in a line with more than one hyphen in PCRE:

```sh
(?:(?:^|\s)(?=(?:[^\s-]*-){2})|(?!^)\G)[^\s-]*\K-
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZcehM/2)

**Explanation:**

- `[^\s-]*` matches a character that is not a whitespace and not a hyphen
- `(?=(?:[^\s-]*-){2})` is lookahead to make sure there are at least 2 hyphens in a non-whitespace substring
- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `\K` resets match info

---

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I forgot to include in my question was that the phrases could be in a single sentence, so in something like "Coca-Cola Step-By-Step", the hyphen in "Coca-Cola" is also matched, where I would only want to match on those within the "Step-By-Step" phrase

Comment: It did work out until I realized I needed a java regular expression and \K is unsupported :/ . I am trying to make use of this for a custom tokenizer in our elasticsearch cluster

Comment: I have added a Java specific regex in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This matches at least two words each followed by hyphen, followed by another word (I'm assuming you don't want to allow hyphen at the very beginning or end, only between words).

```
(\w+-){2,}\w+
```

Comment: How can I specifically make this match on the hyphens and not the words surrounding them or entire phrase?

Comment: That's harder because a lookbehind has to be fixed-length, so it can't match a variable-length word before the first hyphen. Why not just use a capture group to capture the hyphen?